# Is there a direct instruction for RESPONSE.REDIRECT to go to previous page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Web application (Help Desk Ticket System) with an inbox to monitor incoming requests and made some filter buttons that help the user arrange the requests based on requester name, creation date, etc.

Every filter will simply call the same page but will add some code to the query string. 
Example, if the user presses a button labeled [Sort by Date] here is the code behind for that button:

```
Response.Redirect("Inbox.aspx?Filter=DATE")
```

another button will similarly execute:

```
Response.Redirect("Inbox.aspx?Filter=NAME")
```

A GridView will be populated with some rows (Summary of the incoming requests) and ordered by the preference of the user.

Once the user has decided to view the full details any of the incoming requests, a click on any row will lead to

```
Response.Redirect("Details.aspx?REQ_ID=123") 
'where 123 is the request number the user clicked
```

Then the user is given a chance to update/edit the request using several buttons on the Details.aspx page, but every button will need to return the user to the inbox with the preference of filter that the user had before vising the Details.aspx page.

In other words, I would like to do the following once the user presses a button on the Details.aspx page

```
    Sub btnUpdateRequest() Handles btnUpdateRequest.Click

    'My code here for the button action (update/edit/send/cancel)
    ' once the job is done, return the user to the Inbox.aspx page with the same filter

    Response.Redirect("javascript:History.Back()")
    End Sub
```

But I know that Response.Redirect does not accept javascript, and I don't want to split the code between Code Behind file, and ASPX file (adding OnClientClick attribute) because I will need to perform both VB instructions and also redirecting the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could redirect to the referrer URL. You should probably check first to see if it is available.

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri != null) {
    Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Comment: This is the very thing I was looking for, although written in C# but that is not a big problem. Thank you very much @Jon

Answer (score 0):

Below might help you. Place this code inside button click()

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("goBack", "<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">window.history.go(-1);</script>")
```

Comment: Than you very much for the very quick reply @Saurabh . I will try it but will this trigger the redirect process immediately or would it allow the event to happen at a later time?

Comment: @Jon has posted the code I was looking for. Thank you very much anyways. I would need to redirect the user right after I am done processing the request, so having the script added and then activated some other time might not be very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Page.` you could use `ClientScript.`, similar to this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    GetType(String), 
    "goBack", 
    "<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">window.history.go(-2);</script>")
```

The `.go(-2)` in my suggestion is necessary (ReportViewer).