# No action in Form, no redirect, ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET application inside a form tag. When I click a certain div I manually call a click event in a hidden `asp:button` with JS to make some dataprocessing and submit some data. Since the form doesn't have an action tag the form redirects to a 404 page not found page because of the button postback.

I can't know the previous page so I tried with

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
```

but it doesn't work. **This isn't ASP.NET MVC** so the suggestions I found in these pages aren't relevant: [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339346/how-to-be-redirected-to-the-previous-page-using-response-redirect-in-asp-net-c) [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410731/is-there-a-direct-instruction-for-response-redirect-to-go-to-previous-page?rq=1) [Question3](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/56270-posting-server-but-staying-same-page)

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: If you try Request.RawUrl?

Comment: I suggest either using a ViewState or Session to store the current page before redirect.There is also the possibility of passing it in the querystring as a parameter like returnurl=yoururl.

Comment: @Quispie I tried and it did not work. (besides being 1000x slower for some reason).